# IIS hosted WCF and requests from IPv6

Tags: wcf, iis, ipv6

Just got a customer that had IPv6 enabled on his network and wasn't able to build up an connection to our WCF service.
Once disabled a connection could be established.
Wonder if that was probably just an misconfiguration ons their side...or is my wcf client/service or IIS not IPv6 capable?

Do I need to make any adjustments on my side to accept requests from IPv6 adresses?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the website that host your WCF is IPv6 accessible first. Try to use browser to access svc file to see what happened.

Check your IIS bindings, to see whether IPv6 address is enabled for your service/website.